# I Want to calculate discount in percentage and rupees based on radio button selection

Tags: php, jquery

I have two radio buttons first discount in percentage and second discount in rupees. based on selection of radio button i want to display result.Please provide me function for the same or suggest some other method.Front end is in php language.

Comment: Post your code in a jsfiddle or similar.

Comment: why do not you try simple maths by getting value of radio button checked.
if($discount_method=='percentage'){
....
}
if($disocunt_method=='rupee'){
....
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Amount : <input type="text" id="amount" value="100" />
Discount : <input type="text" id="discount" value="10" />
Balance : <input type="text" id="balance" value="90" />
Discount in Percentage : <input type="radio" class="discount-type" value="1" checked name="dc" />
Discount in Amount : <input type="radio" class="discount-type" value="2" name="dc"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     var total, discount;
     $('input[type=radio][name=dc]').change(function() {
        total = $('#amount').val();
        discount = $('#discount').val();
        if (this.value == '1') {
            $('#balance').val(total-((discount/100)*total));
        }
        if (this.value == '2') {
            $('#balance').val(total-discount);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: if i want to calculate st and vat what is the procedure @Jobz

Comment: if (this.value == '3') {
            $('#Total').val(total1+((total1*1)* st/100));
        }
        if (this.value == '4') {
           $('#Total').val(total1+(total1*1)* vat/100);

Comment: I used this...suppose st is 15.5%...total is 400...then answer should be 462....its showing me 40062

Comment: how do i create this fiddle...i dont know...i m trying

Comment: For example in your above code ... $('#balance').val(total-((discount/100)*total));......if i place + in place of - it will not work  @Jobz